# Slick 2.0.0 : How to write to MySQL DB a date and time data expressed in UTC timezone?

Tags: scala, jodatime, slick

I cannot figure out how to write a date and time data to MySQL. I've read about mappings, but I cannot find clear examples... The ones I found are on Slick 1.0 and I cannot import the classes they used in those examples, possibly due to refactoring in Slick 2.0.0 (I'm going crazy!)

Could anybody please write a clear example for me (including all the imports)

I'm using jodatime in my code. My requirements are:

jodatime with UTC -> any Slick 2.0 aware date and time with UTC representation and back

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

java.sql.Date and java.sql.Time are supported out of the box.

There is third-party support for Joda:

https://github.com/tototoshi/slick-joda-mapper

https://gist.github.com/dragisak/4756344

You can also write your own mappers:

http://slick.typesafe.com/doc/2.0.0/userdefined.html

Comment: I followed the example in the Slick Documentation for my own mapper, but I cannot get from where to import MappedColumnType. Could you please tell me what's the full package name?

Comment: The docs link the name to the API docs, where it is defined `scala.slick.driver.JdbcProfile`. You can import it from its companion object. However it should also come with the usual import, like `import scala.slick.driver.H2Driver.simple._`.